# MIT App Inventor Adding Standard Number to Time?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am trying to find the time you should arrive at point B from point A.

So far I have `Miles * 60 / Speed = Minutes to arrive.`

I would like to add `Start Time + Minutes to arrive = Arrival Time`

**The issue I have is figuring out a way to show the Arrival Time.
Specifically is there a way to get the number to add to a time and show the new time?**

Consider this:

- variable `miles` is 10.3
- variable `speed` is 12
- variable `startTime` is 11:07

Now I would like the result to be 11:58

To get the minutes used, I use this snippet:
`Miles * 60 / Speed = Minutes`

And I would like to add like so:
`Start Time + Minutes = Arrival Time`

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYejy.jpg)
[image]

Comment: You need to make use of variables.  http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/concepts/variables.html

Comment: [see my answer in the App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/xu0DX7XC_II/IqCLABuMAgAJ)

Comment: You might want to read my answer in the forum again... Protip: use the clock component to calculate with date and time...